# Скрытое поле в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Сервер возвращает 3 параметра:

```
id
imageUrl
text
```

Для отображения данных я использую RecyclerView. ImageUrl и Text соответственно пихаю в ImageView и TextView. Параметр id я использую для получения дополнительных данных. Но не совсем понятно как привязать id к элементам imageUrl и text. Ведь он не привязан к визуальным элементам. Как получить к нему доступ?

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    private List<News> news;
    private  Context mContext;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<News> news, Context mContext) {
        this.news = news;
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public   void deleteItems()
    {
        news.clear();
    }
    public void  loadNews(List<News> news){
        this.news = news;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carder_new, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        News news = this.news.get(position);
        holder.text1.setText(news.getTitle());
           Picasso.with(mContext).load(this.news.get(position).getPreviewImage()).resize(150, 120).into
                (holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.news.size();
    }

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{

    private TextView text1;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

        text1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        text3.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.getId();
        Log.e("Axixa", "onClick " + getPosition());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: зачем вам привязать id к элементам imageUrl и text?

Comment: Суть задачи стоит чтобы организовать master-detail в RV. Я нажимаю на элемент RV, получаю конкретный id и используя этот id отправляю запрос на сервер. Сервер возвращает мне подробную информацию о новости с id

Comment: метод getPosition() получает позицию елемента

Comment: ну так позиция никак не относится к id. Id нам дает сервер. Как привязать id к какому нибудь полю?

Answer (score 2):

В вашей модели,хранящей данные о каждой новости, вам необходимо сделать **третье поле** - переменную с геттерами и сеттерами для хранения `ID` - значения `id` на новость на сервере.
При получении данных с сервера в `List <News>` заполнять не два, а три поля - в каждом элементе коллекции `news` будет модель, связанная тремя параметрами: `Text`, `Image` и `ID`.
В адаптере вы выводите два первых параметра, а при клике получаете значение `getPosition()` - это значение теперь  будет связано не только с первыми двумя параметрами, которые вы видите на экране, но и с третьим `ID`.
То есть, обратившись к элементу коллекции с номером `getPosition()`, вы можете получить из модели `ID`, связанный с отображаемыми по данной позиции `Text` и `Image`. Номер позиции в адаптере соответствует номеру элемента в коллекции `news`.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.getId();
        Long id = news.get(getPosition()).getID();
    }
```

PS: Метод холдера `getPosition()` считается устаревшим и не всегда возвращает верный результат, вместо него предлагается использовать [`getApapterPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()) или [`getLayoutPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition())

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть список данных (объектов с полем id). При клике по элементу вы получаете его позицию в списке, коя соответствует списку данных. Засим позиция кликнутого элемента соответствует порядковому номеру объекта в списке данных.

Таким образом вам надо просто перенести назначение обработчиков нажатий из объявления класса **ViewHolder** в метод **onBindViewHolder**, в котором на вход подана позиция в списке, к коей можно получить доступ в обработчике нажатий.